# Having trouble playing video in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I created a really small web component in which I have to play a video. I'm using a youtube video url to play the video inside component but it gives me the following error:

> Refused to load media from
>   'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLaWOkc3bC8' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src 'self'
>   *.visualforce.com https://resourceful-wolf-s3e06s-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com blob:".

I added https://www.youtube.com to CSP trusted sites but the issue persisits.

below is the code:

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Dark Phoenix Trailer">
        <video id="darkPhoenix" width ="200" height= "150">
            <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLaWOkc3bC8" type="video/mp4">
                Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
        <div>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Play Video" title="Play Video" onclick={playVideo} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Gts_videoPlayer extends LightningElement {
    vid;
    renderedCallback(){
        this.vid = this.template.querySelector('video');
    }
    playVideo(){
        this.vid.play();

    }
}
```

Any help on fixing this? Also, can I use the same approach to play video from some other source?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 Video tag requires specific format and youtube videos are not mp4 format always. Hence youtube never recommends to use this tag.They have built [api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) to support embedding youtube videos.

Salesforce dev evangelist has already built one [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/07/play-youtube-videos-through-lightning-web-components.html) using embed api and you can adopt the approach.

If you are interested in reading why using video tags may not be reliable approach for youtube videos, i suggest you read these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157377/show-youtube-video-source-into-html5-video-tag).

Other simple approach is use iframe like below using the copy embed code that you can get for the video.

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Dark Phoenix Trailer">
        <iframe width="300" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SLaWOkc3bC8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: The "simple" approach (iframe) works perfectly